# Short story about a pursuit across time-rates

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was in an anthology from way back in the 60s or 70s when I was just getting into SF - I've no idea who the author was.

One man pursues another as he slips across different **time rates** - the only detail I can remember is something towards the end about seeing "by the grey light of gravity".

Comment: Why was he pursuing him? Do you remember anything else about the story (characters, events)? How were the different time-rates presented? By what means did they travel in time?

Comment: Is there any chance it was Asimov's "The End of Eternity"?

Answer (score 5):

In Murray Leinster's ["The Eternal Now"](https://prehistorian.wordpress.com/2019/03/20/the-eternal-now-1944-by-murray-leinster/), time is slowed down and there is some kind of red-shift effect that makes gravity waves visible, everything looks gray because regular light is invisible.

Comment: Could you edit in any relevant information from the link in case it goes down? You also might consider [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161).

Comment: Wow - I think this is the one! Many, many thanks! Now to find a copy!